# How to find a string from array of objects using underscore js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, sails.js

Hi I'm trying to perform _.find using underscore function. When I tried to execute it, it returns undefined, but all my string search from this object is always there. Please find below my sample data structure:

```
oArrays = [
  { 
    "c":"ABC", 
    "sc":[
      { "name":"ABC123", "t1":0, "t2":0 },
      { "name":"ABC456", "t1":0, "t2":0 },
      { "name":"ABC789", "t1":0, "t2":0 }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    "c":"BCDEF", 
    "sc":[
      { "name":"JJHS", "t1":0, "t2":0 },
      { "name":"JKHJYH", "t1":0, "t2":0 },
      { "name":"DKJHKJ", "t1":0, "t2":0 }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    "c":"ZYXV", 
    "sc":[
      { "name":"KDSKD", "t1":0, "t2":0 },
      { "name":"PWIFGF", "t1":0, "t2":0 },
      { "name":"WWSD", "t1":0, "t2":0 }
    ] 
  }, 
]

_.find(oArrays, function(item){
   return item.sc.name==="ABC123" ;
});
```

the above codes doesn't worked, result is undefined.... Is it possible to execute it in one _.find function only?

I tried to used multiple _.map function, it works. But as much as possible I dont want to use it coz it will have too many loops. (sample below)

```
_.map(oArrays, function(item){
  _.find( item.sc, function( item2 ) {
    return item2.name==="ABC123" ;
  });
});
```

Ooops, btw I'm executing these codes using sails-controller.

really appreciate any help :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`item.sc.name` is never a string, as you're trying to compare it to. In fact, it's actually `undefined`. But `item.sc` is an array of objects with the `name` property.

You have to check if among the `name` properties there's what you're looking for:

```
_.find(oArrays, function(item) {
    return _.contains(_.pluck(item.sc, "name"), "ABC123");
});
```

Comment: Hi MaxArt thanks so much for your reply, I ran this code and it works, it returned the object of matched search.

Comment: Also, is it possible that inside the _.find function can also retrieve the second-level index of found search?

Comment: @Nina Yes. Instead of `_.contains`, you can use `_.indexOf`: this will return the index of the item with the name you're looking for, or `-1` if not found. Then you can do `return index !== -1;`.